# How to add to lines not including [ in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm using ^[^[] to locate all lines that don't begin with a [. I want to add the letter X to all of those lines, however with the replace function it selects the first letter, so if the line was hello, I would end up replacing it and it would read Xello.

Is there some parameter I can use so it won't select the first letter? Alternatively a function which adds instead of replaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the `Find what` field you must use `(^[^[])`
- In the `Replace` field you must use `X$1`

Don't forget to check first `Regular expression` in the `Search mode`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?!\[)`
- Replace with: `X`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : Beginning of line
(?!     : start negative lookahead, make sure we don't have the following character
  \[    : open bracket
)       : end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
X       : the text you want to add
```

**Example file:**

```
abc
[12]
a[45]b
[abcd]
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Xabc
[12]
Xa[45]b
[abcd]
```